# Are layer-hosting NSViews allowed to have subviews?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, calayer, nsview

Layer-hosting NSViews (so NSViews that you supply a CALayer instance for and set it with `setLayer:`) can obviously contain subviews. Why obviously? Because in Apple's own [Cocoa Slides sample code project](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaSlides/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004072), you can check a checkbox that switches the `AssetCollectionView` from being layer-backed to being layer-hosting:

```
- (void)setUsesQuartzCompositionBackground:(BOOL)flag {
    if (usesQuartzCompositionBackground != flag) {
        usesQuartzCompositionBackground = flag;

        /* We can display a Quartz Composition in a layer-backed view tree by 
           substituting our own QCCompositionLayer in place of the default automanaged 
           layer that AppKit would otherwise create for the view.  Eventually, hosting of 
           QCViews in a layer-backed view subtree may be made more automatic, rendering 
           this unnecessary.  To minimize visual glitches during the transition, 
           temporarily suspend window updates during the switch, and toggle layer-backed 
           view rendering temporarily off and back on again while we prepare and set the 
           layer.
        */
        [[self window] disableScreenUpdatesUntilFlush];
        [self setWantsLayer:NO];
        if (usesQuartzCompositionBackground) {
            QCCompositionLayer *qcLayer = [QCCompositionLayer compositionLayerWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Cells" ofType:@"qtz"]];
            [self setLayer:qcLayer];
        } else {
            [self setLayer:nil]; // Discard the QCCompositionLayer we were using, and let AppKit automatically create self's backing layer instead.
        }
        [self setWantsLayer:YES];
    }
}
```

In the same `AssetCollectionView` class, subviews are added for each image that should be displayed:

```
- (AssetCollectionViewNode *)insertNodeForAssetAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    Asset *asset = [[[self assetCollection] assets] objectAtIndex:index];
    AssetCollectionViewNode *node = [[AssetCollectionViewNode alloc] init];
    [node setAsset:asset];
    [[self animator] addSubview:[node rootView]];
    [nodes addObject:node];

    return [node autorelease];
}
```

When I build and run the app and play around with it, everything seems to be fine.

However, in [Apple's NSView Class Reference for the `setWantsLayer:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setWantsLayer:) it reads:

> When using a layer-hosting view you should not rely on the view for
>   drawing, nor should you add subviews to the layer-hosting view.

What is true? Is the sample code incorrect and it's just a coincidence that it works? Or is the documentation false (which I doubt)? Or is it OK because the subviews are added through the animator proxy?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When AppKit is "layer hosting" we assume you may (or may not) have a whole subtree of layers that AppKit doesn't know about.

If you add a subview to the layer hosted view, then it might not come out in the right sibling order that you want. Plus, we sometimes add and remove them, so it might change depending on when you call setLayer:, setWantsLayer: or when the view is added or removed from the superview. On Lion (and before) we remove the layers that we "own" (ie: layer backed) when the view is removed from the window (or superview).

It is okay to add subviews...their children-sibling-order in the sublayers array just might not be deterministic if you have sibling-layers that aren't NSViews.

Comment: Is this still accurate in 2019?

Comment: It should be. If they changed sometime to make it not work, then log a bug!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's the "right" answer to this. But I do think that the CocoaSlides example works within the boundaries of what the docs say you "shouldn't" do. In the example, look at where the `insertNodeForAssetAtIndex:` method is called, and you'll see that it only happens when the view is being populated, *before* it ever is assigned a layer or has setWantsLayer: called on it.

The docs don't say that a layer-hosted view can't contain any subviews, they just say that you can't *add* and subviews to one. At the point in time when those subviews are added, the main view hasn't yet become a layer-hosting view. After it has been turned into a layer-hosting view by having a manually created layer assigned to it, no more subviews are added.

So there's really no contradiction between the docs and this particular example. That being said, it could be interesting to explore this further, maybe by switching on the QC background layer right from the start, e.g. by sticking a `[self setUsesQuartzCompositionBackground:YES];` right inside `initWithFrame:`.

**SPOLIER ALERT:**
It seems to work just fine. The creation of the display is a bit slower (not surprising with all that QC animation going on), but apart from that it's smooth sailing.

Comment: Thanks, Jack! Interesting observation about "adding" vs "already having" subviews. Maybe the docs are out of date, as they are about this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720062/are-layer-backed-nsview-siblings-allowed-to-overlap/10720422#10720422

Answer (score 0):

One comment about this code from Apple: it's busted.

When you first start the app up, note the nice gradient background.  Turn QC on, then off.

Poof, no more gradient background.