# Sibling NSView z-ordering in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

How does z-ordering work with sibling NSViews in Cocoa? I'm confused because I'm finding conflicting sources of information in Apple's docs and APIs. (Note: Subviews are obviously rendered on top of its parent view, I am talking explicitly about sibling views here).

**Hypothesis A**: *"Yes, you can define the z-order of sibling `NSViews`"*

- In `IB` you can place views on top of each other and they will always be composited in the way you'd expect.
- There's buttons in Xcode under the `Editor` menu named "Send to Back", "Send Forward" etc.
- The `NSView` also has a method named `- (void)addSubview:(NSView *)aView positioned:(NSWindowOrderingMode)place relativeTo:(NSView *)otherView;` which seems to imply that there is a well defined ordering.

**Hypothesis B**: *"No way, z-order of sibling `NSViews` is undefined at runtime. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Don't trust it!"*

- Apple's Docs ([View Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH4-SW1)) state: `For performance reasons, Cocoa does not enforce clipping among sibling views or guarantee correct invalidation and drawing behavior when sibling views overlap. If you want a view to be drawn in front of another view, you should make the front view a subview (or descendant) of the rear view.`

So which one is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, NSView siblings **are** allowed to overlap, the Apple docs are out of date: [Are layer-backed NSView siblings allowed to overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720062/are-layer-backed-nsview-siblings-allowed-to-overlap)

Also, the z-order depends on the order of the subviews in the parent view's `subviews` array.

Comment: What if views are not layer backed?

Comment: No, Apple docs are not out of date. There are cases when displaying won't work correctly in case views are not layered. explanation in comments at the link above.

Comment: @dev_null Could you specify which link and which comments you mean? Thanks!

Comment: yours above: stackoverflow.com/a/10729201/171933 , my comments below. The thing I state is that there is such kind of NSView (I can't say precisely what technology is used inside chromium browser) that siblings which are higher in Z order will be ignored. I suspect that having any opengl view is enough for this.

Comment: Your mention of the order of the subviews array led me to pull up my project.xib in a text editor and move my imageview near the top of the <subviews> array just under the <box... and very first <imageview..., in order to restore my preferred image as background.

Answer (score 3):

I've been solving the same issue and found that at least on Mavericks it works only with layer backed views. I didn't have chance so far to test it on other OS X versions, but on Mavericks you have to set `wantsLayer` to `YES` on all views you want to overlap in order to make it work.