# Draw a transparent overlay over another NSView, specifically, a WebView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift, nsview

I need to draw a transparent overlay over another NSView, specifically, a WebView. The goal is to display some notification text with a semi-transparent background. For my first experiment I created an Overlay view that just displays a green square:

```
class Overlay: NSView {
    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        NSColor.greenColor().setFill()
        NSBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 1000, height: 1000)).fill()
    }
}
```

and then, in my code, I instantiate them and add them like this:

```
webView = WebView(frame: bounds)
overlay = Overlay(frame: bounds)

addSubview(webView)
addSubview(overlay)
```

To my surprise, that only works with some pages. For example, if you go to https://twitter.com/screensavrninja, it grayes out the whole page and shows you a sign out pop-in. Both the graying out and the pop-in happen on top of the green square.

Why is that happening? What's the appropriate way to have an overlay and have it remain on top?

Answer (score 2):

In AppKit, the order of subviews does not necessarily determine the order that they will be drawn in.

> For performance reasons, Cocoa does not enforce clipping among sibling views or guarantee correct invalidation and drawing behavior when sibling views overlap. If you want a view to be drawn in front of another view, you should make the front view a subview (or descendant) of the rear view.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH4-SW16)

However, if you make the view layer-backed, they [respect the ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720062/are-layer-backed-nsview-siblings-allowed-to-overlap/10729201). So you could try enabling that.

Otherwise, you could use a child window to show the overlay. This has the advantage of being able to extend beyond the bounds of the parent, and is fairly common in Cocoa. See the [documentation for NSWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-SW37).

Comment: The context of this is a screensaver, so, another Window is out of the question as far as I understand windows. I'll look into layer-backed views.

Comment: OS X screensavers are curious beasts. Good luck!

Comment: I'm not sure how to square this up with what the docs for [`NSView.subviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483539-subviews) says: "The current view acts as the superview for each subview. The order of the subviews may be considered as being back-to-front, but this does not imply invalidation and drawing behavior." Which is correct?